# Sound problem in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, xubuntu

I have recently installed Xubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and having some sound issues.The sound stutters,distorts ,buzzes.This happens no matter it is a video or an mp3 playing. Its frequency is unstable as sometimes it starts straightaway when I start playing a music/video or after 30 seconds and so on.And it repeats in short intervals.And whenever this problem occurs ,the sound level indicator pops up.Any suggestions are welcome. Regards.